# progress wheel not working in code

Tags: android, progress-bar, material-design, progress

Hi i am using progress wheel for loading it is working when i am using in `xml` and calling in java. But it is not working in code side itself my code is written bellow.

this is working

```
 ProgressWheel s=(ProgressWheel)findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
s.setBarColor(Color.GREEN);
s.spin();
```

this code is not working

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        ProgressWheel progressWheel = new ProgressWheel(DriverLogin.this);
        progressWheel.setBarColor(Color.GREEN);
        progressWheel.setLayoutParams(params);
        progressWheel.spin();
```

when i am creating `ProgressWheel` from code itself it is not working how to solve this

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in more details (what do you expect to happen and what actually happens). "Is not working" is a little too broad description

Comment: I suppose that by not working you mean that there is no ProgresWheel displayed? I suppose ProgressWheel is some kind of View, so your second snippet is not working because you created a View, you just initialized a variable but you haven't added it into your view hierarchy. So you will have to call [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) method of your root view. But personally I would suggest you to use the first approach you wrote

Comment: @Chaosit is there any simple way for designing my progress bar in code

Comment: I would suggest using [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)